# adding a property to an object in js

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

I have jstree populated with this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var treesList = {!trees};
        for(j=0; j<treesList.length; j++) {
            console.log(treesList[j]);
            $("#jstree"+treesList[j].attr.promotion_item).jstree({ // here we define the tree structure
                "core" : { "animation" : 200 },
                "json_data" : { "data" : treesList[j]}, 
                "themes" : {"dots" : false, "theme" : "classic"},
                "types" : { "types" : {
                    "default" : { "icon" : { "image" : null } },
                } },
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" , "types"]
            });  
        }
        rerenderTable();
     });
```

I want to set the href attribute for the json_data
If I print the treesList element, I get that data has a title but not an href attribute.

How can I add it with js in order for jstree to view it and populate it in the generated li element? I've tried with:

```
treesList[j].data.attr = "";
treesList[j].data.attr.href = "link";
```

but I get an undefined value.

This is what I have:

```
Object { title="Iphone3S"}
```

What I got:

```
Object { title="Iphone3S", attr=""}
```

What I think I need to makethe jstree link to work

```
Object { title="Iphone3S", attr= {href="link"}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513301/jstree-setting-href-attributes-in-json-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
treesList[j].data.attr= {href:"link"};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many error, like:

```
treesList[j].data.attr = "";
treesList[j].data.attr.href = "link";
```

should be:

```
treesList[j].data.attr = {};
treesList[j].data.attr.href = "link";
```

and the following is a syntax error:

```
Object { title="Iphone3S", attr= {href="link"}}
```

should be:

```
Object { title="Iphone3S", attr: {href : "link"}}
```